# Please can you help me identify a rose with sentimental value?

Tags: identification, roses

My late mother had a rose that was grown as a cutting from her grandmothers rose garden. I am very new to gardening, but I have managed to grow several cuttings (luck > judgement).

It would be wonderful to know more about the rose. Especially if its a climber or not.

I think it might be a hybrid tea(?):

[image: Rose to identify]

[More pictures, of these roses, are at Google Photos](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOJdaQlnPurB7eccZjpRIuyiW-qAnVBK-V-4jBItUSU-tk6PLCTPjQ3PCLI2nWDSQ?key=VGJxNE5HQUdvR2RPTUlYSXJGbmVwSGl5WGpMOWFB).

It's the pink one in the pictures (the fully grown one is my mothers, the ones in pots are my cuttings). I'm less interested in the peach coloured rose...but for a bonus point?

Comment: You haven't mentioned fragrance - is there any to the flowers? And its difficult to tell how many petals are in an open flower, can you count them please? What makes you wonder if its a climber or not?

Comment: And what part of the world are you in, or at least, where was your grandmother's garden...

Comment: Bamboo, one can count the petals for an ID on roses?  At least to find if climber, tea, floribunda?  Huh!  I've never even tried to ID someone's rose...overwhelming.

Comment: Many thanks for replies, im just starting out as a gardener...so im very grateful for all your replies. Re: fragrance....as a inexperienced rose sniffer...id say the fragrance was sweet and modestly strong...not sure if that helps?

Comment: I'm in the UK, South Wales, clay soil, Westerly aspect. My mothers garden was in North Yorkshire, and my grandmothers garden was in Halifax, UK

Comment: I think there are about 27-30 petals per flower head..although im not sure im being accurate in that measurement....  ..it may help to know that my grandmother was born in 1915 and the rose cuttings i have grown are definitely a descendant/cutting from a rose in her garden...but it may go further back to my great grandmother...although this is less certain...

Answer (score 2):

Could it be Rosa 'Buxom Beauty'? Pink, hybrid tea, strong scent, Award of Garden Merit RHS in 2012, but much older that that.

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Rosa_%27Parole%27